# How to add only 1 marker at my live location in the application

Tags: android, flutter

```
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {

    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        // This marker id can be anything that uniquely identifies each marker.
        markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
        position: _lastMapPosition,
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MarkerOptions mOptions = new MarkerOptions();

 // current location latitude and Longitude
 LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

 mOptions.position(currentLatLng);
 mMap.addMarker(mOptions);
 mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 10));
```

Pass the current location cordinates to get marker added to the map, there can be other customizations available for the mOptions created.